# CSV export ExtensionAttributes with values

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Trying to export list of AD Users and Extension Attributes but only export a column if there is a value for at least one user. For onscreen results I have this working but when I export to csv, it only gives me one column for extensionattribute5 which is the one that most people have a value for. There are a number of other extension attributes that some users have values for but not all 15 extension attributes have values. I only want it to export columns that have a value, the same as it does in the screen output before I try and send it to CSV. I know I can select all 15 of them by explicitly entering each one but I am hoping to only have it export all of those extension attributes columns that have at least one value.

Below is how it is displayed on screen if using select extensionattibute* but the exported CSV only returns the particular extension attribute that most users have a value for, i.e. it has only one column for extensionattibute5

User1
name
mail
extensionAttribute*

User2
name
mail
extensionAttribute2
extensionAttribute6

This is my current command:

```
get-aduser -filter * -SearchBase 'OU=Users,OU=division,DC=org,DC=company,DC=place,DC=us' -properties * |  select name,mail,extensionAttribute*,userprincipalname, @{name="proxyaddresses";expression={($_.proxyaddresses | Where-Object {$_ -like "*smtp:*"}) -join ","}} |  Export-Csv c:\temp\myfile.csv -notypeinformation  -Encoding UTF8
```

Comment: you MUST have the same columns in a CSV file for each and every row. any other structure is NOT a CSV file. [*grin*]

Comment: That is not what I am asking. The output to the screen is as below.  But the spreadsheet will only have extensionattribute2  column since most users have value for that. if a user has no values for any extensionattibute it will show on the screen as extensionAttribute*  

User1
name               
mail               
extensionAttribute* 

User2 
name                
mail               
extensionAttribute2
extensionAttribute6

But the spreadsheet has only attribute2 which is the one that most people have a value.  The csv does not create a column for any of the others.

Comment: PLEASE, add that info to your Question & wrap it in code formatting markers. right ow it is both buried AND nearly unreadable. [*grin*]

Comment: You're going to have to include the properties by name. You can't rely on the wildcard globbing from `Select-Object` to do it because that command will assume the first object in the collection has all the possible properties. You shouldn't be using `-Properties *` with `Get-ADUser` anyways. You're returning a ton more data than you actually need, especially if your domain is using thumbnail photos.

Comment: Thanks Bacon Bits. Both useful pieces of information, that the wildcard will not work for output to CSV. I did manage to get it working for the multiple proxyaddresses as you can see in my PS command but was stuck with the extendedattributes fields.  How do I mark this as answered?